# Como adaptar esse código para telas diferentes

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Estou com um problema ao utilizar um *slider* vertical, o [Swiper Slider](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/) estou utilizando o *MouseWheel control*. 
Meu problema é o seguinte, como ele é um *slider vertical*, preciso definir um tamanho para o `height`, então não consigo deixá-lo responsivo.

Exemplo:

Abaixo encontra-se o arquivo css onde defino o tamanho do `container` que irá comportar os elementos do `slider`.

```
.swiper-container { /*esta classe comporta os slides.*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide { /nesta classe encontram-se os compontes do swiper.container.*/
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
   /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Como podem ver, defini o tamanho do `height` em `900px`, é claro que em telas menores ele continuará com `900px`, preciso que ele se adeque ao tamanho da tela, isto posso resolver com `media-queries`, porém tenho mais um problema, vejam o *script* que efetua a inicialização do *slider*: 
A opção `slidesPerView`, define quantos slides aparecerão na tela por vez, se eu diminuir o `height`, continuarão aparecendo 4 slides :/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//initialize swiper when document ready  
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
      // Optional parameters
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        direction: 'vertical',
        slidesPerView: 4, 
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        mousewheelControl: true
    })        
});
```

O [html](http://codepen.io/fredddd/pen/XdBZbQ) coloquei no pen porque se não o *post* ficaria muito extenso.

Alguma ideia de como resolver? 
Também estou aceitando indicações de algum *vertical slider* melhor.

**Estou utilizando o materialize como framework css.**

Comment: Ola, Na parte de diminuir ou aumentar o numero de imagens, quais vão ser as regras?

Comment: Então, minha ideia seria para que quando o tamanho da tela for menor que 600px apareçam umas 2 imagens, entre 600 e 1024 4 imagens e maior que isso 5 imagens.

Comment: escondi a publicidade. O que pretende é? https://jsfiddle.net/mrpbLL6a/1/

Comment: Legal! Era isso mesmo. Mas acabei resolvendo usando as media-queries mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta! Mas mesmo assim acho que vou fazer dessa forma que você fez, quatro imagens numa tela de 320px é muito hahaha. Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ser dinâmico foi criada a função atualiza.

```
atualiza=function(){
   $('.swiper-container').width($( window ).width());
   $('.swiper-container').height($( window ).height());

   if ($( window ).height()<600){
      mySwiper.slidesPerView=2;
   } else if ($( window ).height()<1024){
      mySwiper.slidesPerView=4;
   } else {
      mySwiper.slidesPerView=5;
   }
};
```

Essa função tem a tarefa de indicar o tamanho do slider e como indicar quantas fotos deverão ser visualizadas.

Foi criado um trigger para se existir alguma mudança com o tamanho da janela chamar a função atualiza.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   atualiza();
});
```

O exemplo no jsfiddle.:
jsfiddle.net/mrpbLL6a/1